# How to allow only tunneled connections to port?

Tags: linux, ssh, port, tunnel

I'd like to make a git-daemon go through a permanent ssh tunnel. I accomplished this task. How do I block any remote untunneled connection to the GIT_DAEMON port (9418 in my case)?

I already tried simple rules in iptables (block everything except localhost):

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d ! localhost --destination-port 9418 -j DROP
```

But it also blocks a tunnel (since it saves source ip address). If I have one more host for firewall it can be simply done by blocking any remote connection to this port, but I need this host to do this job.

The tunnel is created in one of two ways:

For Windows:

```
plink.exe -N -i <key> -L 127.0.0.1:9418:192.168.1.69:9418 tunnel@192.168.1.69
```

For Linux:

```
ssh -N -i <key> -L 127.0.0.1:9418:192.168.1.69:9418 tunnel@192.168.1.69
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try this (**untested**):

```
# accept localhost
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d localhost --destination-port 9418 -j ACCEPT

# send everyone else packing
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 9418 -j DROP
```

Using that `iptables -L` says:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             localhost.localdomain tcp dpt:git
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:git
```

**EDIT**

This is (probably) how your tunnel should be setup:

```
ssh -N -i <key> -L 127.0.0.1:9418:127.0.0.1:9418 tunnel@192.168.1.69
```

**It's important that the second half is `127.0.0.1` and NOT a normal IP**

Comment: Now its tested, but isn't too helpful, it provides same effect as rule in a question :(

Comment: @kravitz Can you explain a little better what the path of the traffic should be ?

Comment: @cnicutar sure, suppose we have three hosts: A, B, C. Host A has a git-daemon running, host B wants to communicate with A (push/pull requests), host C shouldn't be able to access git-daemon at A. I emulate authentication via ssh tunneling. So B creates local tunnel to A (9418 port to 9418, with -L option in openssh), it means that everything that B sends to a local 9418 port goes through ssh (22 port) and occurs at A's 9418 port. I need a filtration mechanism, that will block connections to A:9418, for everything, except tunnels.

Comment: @kravitz I edited my answer. Do you have the tunnel setup _exactly_ that way ? It's very possible to do it with `iptables`, be patient.

Comment: @cnicutar yes, absolutely that way. I also give -N option, to make a non-interactive session. Also tried to connect with a Windows host, with tunnel, made by plink. Both OpenSSH and Plink works smoothly unless I enable filter rules.

Comment: @kravitz I see in your question that the tunner is NOT created **exactly** the way I said. **It should be `127.0.0.1` instead of `192.168.1.69`**.

Comment: @cnicutar my bad :) I tried your suggestion and it works, thanks a lot, also you can edit your answer, that this tunnel must be setup from B, because it wasn't clear for me, and I first tried it on A, and get nothing interesting. And my one-line rule works :)

Answer (score 8):

You can actually achieve this without using iptables at all, by simply making `git-daemon` bind to the loopback interface, eg.

```
git daemon --listen=127.0.0.1
```

This will make it so it is only connectable from localhost, and does not require root privileges to set up.

Comment: thanks, clean and simple. But @cnicutar's advice with correct tunneling deserves "correct answer" mark.